# Android Studio 2021.3.1 doesn't exit

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

Android Studio 2021.3.1 doesn't exit. I click close button and it crashes and gets stuck on the screen.  Windows can't close it. I can close with task manager or by rebooting.

How can I fix this?

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Registry key vcs.annotations.preload is not defined
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.Registry.getBundleValue(Registry.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.RegistryValue.resetToDefault(RegistryValue.java:294)
    at AnnotationsPreloaderEnabler$1.appClosing(AnnotationsPreloaderEnabler.java:21)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeMethod(MessageBusImpl.java:642)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeListener(MessageBusImpl.java:620)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:417)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpWaitingBuses(MessageBusImpl.java:390)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:372)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:33)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$MessagePublisher.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.appClosing(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.doExit(ApplicationImpl.java:574)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.exit(ApplicationImpl.java:554)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.exit(ApplicationImpl.java:543)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ex.ApplicationEx.exit(ApplicationEx.java:75)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ExitAction.actionPerformed(ExitAction.java:20)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:239)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:260)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:239)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$performAction$0(ActionMenuItem.java:277)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:236)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:67)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.performAction(ActionMenuItem.java:269)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:284)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$2(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:541)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:571)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6654)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2790)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:891)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:820)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:757)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:818)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:498)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: I ended up Uninstaling Java and using the ldk included with android studio

Comment: You don't need permission to add a bounty - just wait two days after posting the question, and the bounty link will appear underneath.